# Natural number in SWI-prolog & recursive procedure

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have the next procedure for natural number is SWI-prolog:

```
natural_number(0).
natural_number(s(X)) :- natural_number(X).
```

Now I want to do a recursive call, that stop when we arrive to 0.

My natural number is represented by - `s(0)=0, s(s(0))=1, s(s(s(0)))=2, etc`

So I define:

```
recommend(A, B, natural_number(0)) :-
    dosomeFINITEfunction (a,b).
recommend(a,b,mynumber):-
    dosomeFINITEfunction(a,b),
    recommend (a,b, natural_number(mynumber)).
```

and call with: `3,5,s(0).`
But it gives me the error: `out of local stack`.

What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Someone know the answer please? You need more information?

Comment: Tom, can you be more exact in the snippet you provide? I have an impression it is very inexact. In the first rule of your second snippet there is A,B and also a,b. Is it what is in your code? Do you really have natural_number(0) in the first rule or you have s(0) there?

Answer (score 2):

```
natural_number(s(0), 0).
natural_number(s(s(X)), N) :- natural_number(s(X), S), N is S + 1.
```