# Why can't I assert the following rule in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to define a rule to convert natural numbers to integers [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356405/783743):

```
?- assert(nat_to_int(0, 0)).
true.

?- assert(nat_to_int(s(X), Y):- nat_to_int(X, Z), Y is Z + 1).
ERROR: Uninstantiated argument expected, found _5706 is _5712+1 (2-nd argument)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [8] assert((nat_to_int(...,_5772):-nat_to_int(_5776,_5778)),_5782 is _5788+1)
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

I understand that `Z` has to be instantiated before it can be used in the expression `Y is Z + 1`. However, I don't understand why it wouldn't be instantiated. Doesn't `nat(X, Z)` instantiate `Z`?

I think the problem is that `X` itself might not be instantiated. Hence, it wouldn't be able to figure out what `Z` should be. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Add additional round brackets: `assert(( nat_to_int(s(X), Y):- nat(X, Z), Y is Z + 1 ))`.

Comment: @false So, this was just a syntactic problem?

Comment: Also, use preferably either `asserta1` or `assertz/1`, which are standard predicates, instead of `assert/1`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Yes. And in your case, as Paulo suggests, use `assertz/1` since you probably depend on adding the clause at the end.

Comment: Since unintentionally calling `assert/2` instead of `assert/1` might be a common issue, maybe this should be added as an answer so the outside world sees this as resolved