# How to tell prolog that N is a natural number if N - 1 is a natural number?

Tags: prolog

I am very new to Prolog and I am trying to do a simple recursive example.
My KB is:

```
    natural(0).
    natural(n) :- natural(n - 1).
```

Then my query is:

```
    natural(1).
```

and the answer is false.

From what I read, numbers in Prolog are constants like 'book' and this might be
causing the problem, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237162/natural-number-in-swi-prolog-recursive-procedure

Comment: In Prolog, variables MUST start with a capital letter (or underscore if it's anonymous). You're trying to use lower case letters, which makes them *atoms*. In addition, Prolog *does not* evaluate expressions inline. So the call `natural(N-1)` does not compute `N-1` then call `natural`. What it does is simply pass the term `N-1` (or internally, `'-'(N, 1)` to `natural`. If you're "very new" to Prolog, then you should start with a basic language tutorial and manual, then attempt writing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
natural(0).
natural(N) :- M is N - 1, natural(M).
```

Prolog is not an imperative language and natural is not a function.
What happens here is I'm unifying M with N - 1 and then look if M is natural.

So, translating to imperative, use `is` for assignment.
Also keep in mind that variables must start with uppercase letters, lowercase letters are for constants.

Comment: `natural(-1).` loops

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog,

```
nat(N) :- between(0, infinite, N).
```

works for both testing and generating natural numbers.